# how to parse the given string in to meaning ful json?

Tags: java, json, httpclient

I have got this value from a web site through `HttpClient`.

```
[
    {
        "scout": "webdriver",
        "short_version": "4.3",
        "long_name": "iPad",
        "api_name": "ipad",
        "long_version": "4.3.",
        "automation_backend": "webdriver",
        "os": "Mac 10.4"
    },
    {
        "scout": "webdriver",
        "short_version": "5.0",
        "long_name": "Firefox",
        "api_name": "firefox",
        "long_version": "14",
        "automation_backend": "webdriver",
        "os": "Mac 10.5"
    },
    {
        "scout": "webdriver",
        "short_version": "4",
        "long_name": "Firefox",
        "api_name": "firefox",
        "long_version": "15",
        "automation_backend": "webdriver",
        "os": "Mac 10.6"
    },
    {
        "scout": "webdriver",
        "short_version": "5",
        "long_name": "Chrome",
        "api_name": "chrome",
        "long_version": "5.0.1.",
        "automation_backend": "webdriver",
        "os": "Mac 10.7"
    }
]
```

I want to get this data into this format:

```
[OS: {Mac10.4,Mac10.5}]
```

etc., the list of OS

and

```
[{api_name: {firefox:{14,15}} }]
```

etc., the list of Browser and their versions.

The list is too long of OS and browsers. 
How to parse it using json or any other method?

Comment: Google provides [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Why not try using that. You can even use the Standard [JSON](http://www.json.org/) to parse your response! And regd how to use them to parse, contact Mr. Google. :)

Comment: Why not parse it with jackson for example and do the grouping in java?

Comment: i hve used json, but it gives error, bcoz as i told the array is too long.

Comment: @JitendraKhedar - Just because the JSON is too big, parsing won't give an error. Your logic for parsing would have been flawed cuz of the length of the json.

Comment: @R.J can u give me the for this, my controller returns json.tostring (let say). now my ajax call is:  $.ajax({
   url: 'getSaucePlatforms.htm',
   type: 'POST',
   async: false,
   success: function(data){
    alert(data);
   }
  });
what would be changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at json-smart library. It's lightweight and fast. (https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/)

Then you can write something like this (just example):

```
    Map<String, List<String>> osMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    osMap.put("OS", new ArrayList<String>());

    Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> apiNameMap = 
        new HashMap<String, Map<String, List<String>>>();
    apiNameMap.put("api_name", new HashMap<String, List<String>>());

    JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) JSONValue.parse(JSON_STRING);
    for (Object obj : ja) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;
        String os = (String) jsonObj.get("os");
        String apiName = (String) jsonObj.get("api_name");
        String longVersion = (String) jsonObj.get("long_version");

        // OS
        if (!osMap.get("OS").contains(os)) {
            osMap.get("OS").add(os);
        }

        // API
        if (!apiNameMap.get("api_name").containsKey(apiName)) {
            apiNameMap.get("api_name")
                    .put(apiName, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        apiNameMap.get("api_name").get(apiName).add(longVersion);

    }

    System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(osMap));
    System.out.println(JSONValue.toJSONString(apiNameMap));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//here getting the json Array from session
    var d  = json1;
    //after making a variable array to put j son data one by one by looping
    var availableTags = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<d.forms.length;i++){
        availableTags[i] = d.forms[i].productName;
    }
});
```